# String replace with another string jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have function which gets the html generated in the iframe and replaces with custom tags.For eg.`<b></b>` tag is replaced with `[b][/b]`. likewise when i press tab key ,`<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space:pre"></span>` is generated, how do i replace this with `[tab][/tab]` custom tag?.Please find the script which replaces bold tag, i tried replacing the whole span tag but it did not work.

Script:

```
function htmltoBBcode() {

var html = $("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html();
  html = html.replace(/\</gi, '[');
  html = html.replace(/\>/gi, ']');

  $("#custom-tag").text(html);


}
```

Any help much appreciated.
[Jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/1zuue8Lo/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function htmltoBBcode() {
    var html = $("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html();
    html = html.replace(/\<span.*?\>/gi, '[tab]');
    html = html.replace(/\<\/span\>/gi, '[/tab]');
    html = html.replace(/\</gi, '[');
    html = html.replace(/\>/gi, ']');

    $("#custom-tag").text(html);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrks8jwa/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much.. this did it .. :-)

Comment: Make sure you keep it in this order or it will fail badly - if you have a few I'd recommend doing the whole tag e.g. `<b>` to `[b]` instead of just `<`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney actually I would keep it how he has it because probably most of the tags he wants to replace don't have attributes with them. The `span` is a special case since it has attributes that need to be cleared also.  I would put all special cases before the replace all `< [ > ]` that way all special cases will be handled first then all other regular cases will be handled without having to specify each case individually...

Answer (score 1):

Very easy!

```js
$('p').click(function(){
  var t = $(this).prop('outerHTML').replace(/</g, '[').replace(/>/g, ']');
$('#custom-tag').text(t);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click me!</p>
<div id="custom-tag"></div>
```

Comment: i have already implemented this, for the bold tag, please see the fiddle. i am trying to match the whole span tag here <span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space:pre"></span> into [tab[[/tabs]. any idea how to do it.thank u for ur help

Comment: i had already implemented this , for bold tab, was trying to match the whole span and replace with custom [tab] tag. Thanks for ur help .

Comment: @Pbk1303 you can convert `<span>` tag to a string and replace it, just like my example. Using `.prop('outerHTML')`

Answer (score 0):

retrieving text from `body` tag will encode it as html, I thought you could save anywhere in a temporary textarea to decode it, than replace in the output, like this:

```
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
    var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
    return textArea.value;
}
```

To replace your `span` tag, replace your `regex` like this:

```
html.replace(/<span>(.+)<\/span>/, '[tab]$1[/tab]');
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zuue8Lo/2/)

Hope it will help! :)

Comment: i don't understand , am trying to replace the whole span tag into custom tag [tab][/tab],i replaced the bold tag into [b][/b]. i am tryin to do the same here.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I forgot the span replace part ^^